# Android App crashes when rotate

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, android-asynctask, orientation

I put the following code in my manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="CPohonApp" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
```

and this is the code in my activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

but still the App crashes when I rotate.

Why does this happen?

I use Android 2.3.3 API 10

thank you

EDIT

this is my log cat

```
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.hdte.sawit/org.hdte.sawit.pohon.CPohonApp}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2832)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at org.hdte.sawit.pohon.CPohonApp.createDialogSend(CPohonApp.java:277)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at org.hdte.sawit.pohon.CPohonApp.onCreateDialog(CPohonApp.java:299)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateDialog(Activity.java:2482)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.Activity.createDialog(Activity.java:882)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.Activity.restoreManagedDialogs(Activity.java:871)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:817)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1096)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1625)
09-25 14:36:31.351: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  ... 12 more
```

Comment: @rajeshwaran.t ok. already. edit.

Comment: as logcat suggests your issue ir related to createDialogSend(CPohonApp.java:277)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should you Dot(.) leading your activity Name.

```
<activity android:name=".CPohonApp" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
```

Or use full package name with your activity name when you declare it in android manifest file.

```
<activity android:name="yourpackagename.CPohonApp" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
```

Comment: solved. `<activity android:name=".pohon.CPohonApp" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>`. what mean Dot(.)?im newbie in android.

Answer (score 0):

Use in each Activity tag

```
<activity android:name=".example"  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code in manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

full code example

```
 <activity
        android:name=".your activity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```